# Sequelize query with include seems to break typescript type pattern

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have noticed this constraint/issue multiple times in our code base, and really wondering if anyone knows a graceful/correct way to handle.

For context:
Sequelize: Version 6

In a nutshell the issue is this:
In sequelize, the return type of a find query that includes an associated table seems wrong.

Code Example:

```
    const session = await Session.findByPk(sessionId, {
      include: [
        {
          model: Application,
          as: 'applications',
        },
      ],
    });

    if (!session || session?.applications.length == 0) throw new Error(`Could not retrieve session ${sessionId}`);
```

In the guard statement, `session?.application` gets a TS error "Property 'applications' does not exist on type 'Session'."

If I create a new type, called for instance "SessionWithApplication" that has the fields of Session with an additional 'application' property, I would think I could use it like this:

```
    type SessionWithApplications<T> = Partial<T> & { applications: Application[] };

    const session: SessionWithApplications<Session> | null = await Session.findByPk(sessionId, {
        include: [
            {
                 model: Application,
                 as: 'applications',
             },
        ],
    });
```

But I get a different TS error on `const session` declaration that reads: Type 'Session | null' is not assignable to type 'SessionWithApplications | null'.

I also thought the association might not be set up in the model, but this is what ours reads:

```
    export class Session extends Model<SessionModel> implements SessionModel {
        public id?: string;
        public created_at?: Date;
        public updated_at?: Date;
        // ...other properties

        public static associations: {
            applications?: Association<Session, Application>;
        };
     ...
```

My expectation was that because `applications` is included as an association in the model (not sure if it is correct to be optional) that the type would be correct when an include of the same name is present, but that isn't what is happening.

If this is really something broken I can write this up as an issue for the Sequelize github, but I am hoping its just that I'm missing something and wanted to check with the community first that I am not overlooking a different solution/pattern that makes this work.

This not working is a pain because we often end up using `//@ts-ignore` on the results of queries with includes.

I took a (brief) look through the open sequelize issues and did not find any that seem to match this.

Any help, advise, or thoughts appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly understand the name od `SessionWithApplications` as ist .
I would try `type ModelWithApplications<T extends Model<any, any>> = T & { applications: Application[] };` instead for naming and usage convention.

As for the function `findByPk`, its defined here as returning `Session | null` and this is not compatible with `Session & { applications: Application[] } | null` due to not contaning that `applications`.

You can use `.findByPk<ModelWithApplications<Session>>(.....)`, or cast the execution of this function as `ModelWithApplications<Session> | null`

Comment: Thank you Seti! I think this is the ticket. The `T extends Model` is really smart and adding that as a type parameter in `.findByPk<>` is what was needed. I'll implement to get it fully working and post here the final product

Comment: So, I tried the code above and still the types are fighting. I get an error:

Type 'Session' is not assignable to type 'ModelWithApplications<Session>'.
            Property 'applications' is missing in type 'Session'.

This is more workable than what I had before though because by making properties optional in the type and then adding manual checks that they exist is still better than  ts-ingore. Will still try to find a solution that uses the sequelize association to infer that applications is a valid field on session when an include is used.

Comment: You might recast it (as unknown as `our type`  because there is no autojoining types on select for sequelize

Comment: Thanks! In the end I went with pretty much the solution above and it is a big improvement over what we had before. Still curious about Sequelize and why it is necessary to declare an association on a model with a name, but also create a custom type with that property again in order to get type checks on the query - it feels like an oversight in the library behaviour, but thanks to your solution it feels cleaner in our code now.

Comment: Its because you may specify any join can be used and Sequelize itself do nto have any useful means of knowing what you do - so you need to specify it by hand